# How to use ToList() to print multiple list items?

Tags: c#, linq

While trying to print items in a list after selecting fields from that list, I get an error saying "cannot convert from list to item". Some queries work, but a few, like the one listed below, require a different print void. I'd like it to work without multiple print voids.

I have tried placing the foreach loop directly under the query, but it can't locate the proper items to print.

```
 List<Item> items = new List<Item>();//create list

 items.Add(new Item()
            {

                ItemGroup = "Electric",
                ItemDescription = "Electric Sander",
                Quantity = 7,
                UnitPrice = 59.98f,
            });//add list item

 var totalValue = items
            .Select(x => (
                x.ItemDescription,
                x.Quantity,
                x.UnitPrice,
                x.Price = TotalValue((int)x.Quantity, (float)x.UnitPrice)
                ))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Quantity)
            .ToList();//create new list for question 1

         PrintItems(totalValue);//print item (throwing error "can't 
 //convert list to item"

  static void PrintItems(List<Item> items)//print void
    {
        foreach (var Item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + Item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: total Value are different than items; totalvalue has itemDescription, Quantity, UnitPrice, Price and items has itemGroup, ItemDescription, Quantity UnitPrice

Comment: Please post the _exact_ error message. I'm guessing the error is telling you that you are using a list of an anonymous type instead of `List<Item>` but it's not clear from your description.

Comment: The type passed into PrintItems is not compatible with input type. Select statement genereates anonymous type, consider changing select statement and implement another PrintItems function which accepts another type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using C# 7 feature to create tuple using LINQ `Select`, meaning you no longer have your `List<Item>` type, but `List<yourTupleType>`.

If that's all you are going to calculate in your Select, then why not just move `TotalValue` to `Item` class

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public float Price
    {
        get
        {
            // your TotalValue logic since you already have quantity and unit Price
            // something like
            return Quantity * UnitPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can just order your collection and pass to PrintItems method.

Another option if you want to have `TotalValue` method outside `Item` class - don't create new object but just recalculate price for each item.

```
items.ForEach(i => i.Price = TotalValue((int)x.Quantity, (float)x.UnitPrice));
PrintItems(items.OrderBy(i => i.Quantity).ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

What your `Select()` statement returns is a Tuple. And a Tuple cannot be converted to an Item

Answer (score 2):

In C#, when you write `(1, "hello", 1.0f)`, you are creating a tuple of type `ValueTuple<int, string, float>` or in short `(int, string, float)`, and it cannot be used interchangeably with a class like

```cs
class NotTuple
{
    public int PropInt { get; set; }
    public string PropString { get; set; }
    public float PropFloat { get; set; }
}
```

(Because they have different type!)

Therefore, when you do

```cs
.Select(x => (
       x.ItemDescription,
       x.Quantity,
       x.UnitPrice,
       x.Price = TotalValue((int)x.Quantity, (float)x.UnitPrice)
    ))
```

you create an `IEnumerable<(string, int, float, float)>`, not a `IEnumerable<Item>`. Later when you call `.ToList()`, the IEnumerable is consumed and materialized to a `List<(string, int, float, float)>`, which is not interchangeable with `List<Item>`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you Skip the PrintItems method? if you can... do this

```
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();//create list

    items.Add(new Item()
        {

            ItemGroup = "Electric",
            ItemDescription = "Electric Sander",
            Quantity = 7,
            UnitPrice = 59.98f,
        });//add list item

         var totalValue = items.GroupBy(a => new { a.Quantity, a.ItemDescription, a.UnitPrice })
                  .Select(g => new { g.Key.ItemDescription, g.Key.Quantity, g.Key.UnitPrice,
                                     Price = g.Sum(s => (int)g.Key.Quantity * (float)g.Key.UnitPrice)
                                     });

    foreach (var Item in totalValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("" + Item);
    }
```